# PRISMA Query is so slow compared to Mysql Raw Query. What am i doing wrong?

Tags: mysql, node.js, prisma

I create an API that uses Prisma, however I find the response super slow. I am new to Prisma so Im not quite sure where the problem is.

Heres how I declared my schema.

```
model tbl_documents {
  id           Int        @id @default(autoincrement())
  ...
  barcode      String     @unique(map: "barcode") @db.VarChar(50)
  name         String     @db.VarChar(255)
  ...
  location     String?    @db.VarChar(100)
  status       String     @default("Pending") @db.VarChar(25)
  ...
  logs         tbl_logs[]
  
}
```

Prisma Query

```
const documents = await prisma.tbl_documents.findMany({
        select: {
            barcode: true,
            name: true,
            description: true,
        },
        where: {
            AND: [
                { location: param.location },
                { status: 'RECEIVED' }
            ].filter(Boolean)
        },
        orderBy: {
            id: 'desc'
        },
    });

    return documents;
}
```

[image: Prisma Query Response for 3x API Call]

It took 1960ms going up to 2407ms.

Mysql Query

```
return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        let sql = `SELECT barcode, name, description  
                    FROM tbl_documents 
                    WHERE location = ? 
                        AND status = 'RECEIVED'`;

        const values = [param.location];

        conn.query(sql, values, function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
                reject(new Error('Failed to get releasable barcodes.'));
                return;
            };

            resolve(result);
        });
    });
```

[image: Mysql Query Response to 3x API Call]

It only took about 250ms. Thats 2seconds difference.

Both are running in the same Nodejs project, but response time difference is so huge.
I tried looking for Prisma Community but could not seem to find an active one.

What might be causing this?
Any pointers would be a great help. Thanks and Cheers!